Is the ship "Borkum" traveling from the Strait of Gibraltar to the Czech Republic?
I'm reading in several German language newspapers the claim that the ship "Borkum" passing currently (that is, May 17) close to the Strait of Gibraltar is delivering weapons to the Czech Republic.
For example ZDFheute:

Mehrere Minister der Regierung wiesen diese Behauptung zurück und beteuerten, das Endziel des Schiffes sei die Tschechische Republik.

In English (DeepL translation):

Several government ministers rejected this claim and asserted that the ship's final destination was the Czech Republic.

Or Die Presse:

das deutsche Schiff werde nun auf Entscheidung der Reederei trotz vorliegender Erlaubnis doch nicht in Cartagena einlaufen und dafür Slowenien ansteuern, um von dort aus nach Tschechien weiterzufahren.

In English:

The German ship will now, at the decision of the shipping company, not enter Cartagena after all, despite having permission to do so, and will instead head for Slovenia in order to travel on to the Czech Republic from there.

Is it likely that the ship is really traveling to the Czech Republic?  I'm no expert (neither in geography nor in logistics), but this seems to me at least a rather unexpected way to deliver cargo to a country that is more 300km away from any sea.  Did the journalists maybe want to say that the cargo is traveling from Slovenia to the Czech Republic (but the ship is not)?   I would have expected that the cargo gets unloaded somewhere and sent by trains/trucks.

I don't think that quote is saying that the ship is literally going to The Czech Republic

"Is it likely"/"is it possible"/"does it make sense" is rather wishy-washy. Surely the question is simply "Is it heading to the Czech Republic?" and that question will be easier to answer once it reaches its destination/

Is it likely? Trivially the ship cannot be destined for Czechia because it is a landlocked country, although its cargo might be. If the country of origin is not easily connected to Czechia by rail, that may be why it makes sense to first send it by sea, the method for most international freight.

The second article you quote has an almost word-for-word copy of the quote from your first article, except it says "Several government ministers rejected this claim and maintained that the final destination of the ship's goods was the Czech Republic". That wording makes much more sense, this just seems to be a translation issue or the article was just skipping some details.

@JoeW I don't know why you don't think that the quotes are saying literally that the ship is going to the Czech Republic.    It says "the final destination of the ship" and "from that point on, it will travel on to".  Maybe the journalist do not mean literally what they are  saying, but they are saying literally that the ship will continue to the Czech Republic.

Because the Czech Republic is a landlocked country and the quote most likely refers to the cargo.

One can travel by ship from Gibraltar to the Czech Republic by using rivers but

The ship needs to be of suitable size for river travel. The Borkum is a container ship which looks way too big for that.

One would travel inland starting in Rotterdam, Netherlands on the Rhine and then across Germany for example along the Danube. This implies that the ship travels through Gibraltar from the Meditarrean into the Atlantic and the goes northward toward the North sea. The Borkum on the other seems to be travelling in the Mediterranean, making a final destination in the Czech Republic not realistic.


In summary, one can transport cargo by ship from Gibraltar to teh Czech Republic but that is not what the Borkum seems to be doing right now.

Coudn't you go up through the Danube?  In any case, I also do not believe that the ship was really going to the Czech Republic.  Indeed, see the answer below.

The Borkum does not travel to the Czech Republic.
According to this article from "eleconomista.es"

El buque Borkum ha decidido suspender su escala en el Puerto de Cartagena poniendo rumbo al puerto esloveno desde el que trasladará su mercancía a la República Checa, según ha comunicado a la Capitanía Marítima y han confirmado a Europa Press fuentes del Ministerio de Transportes.

that is

The Borkum has decided to suspend its stop at the Port of Cartagena, setting course for the Slovenian port from which it will transfer its cargo to the Czech Republic, as it has informed the Maritime Captaincy and sources from the Ministry of Transport have confirmed to Europa Press.

or this one from "Cadena Ser":

[...] se dirige directamente a Eslovenia para trasladar desde allí la carga a Praga.

that is

[...] will travel directly to Slovenia to transfer from there its cargo to Prague.

It is surprising that German journalists get a wrong translation and do not even wonder if what they are saying might be correct.
